# Can't view contacts while call in progress

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, contacts, phone-app

While a phone call is in progress, the phone is always on the "call in progress" screen (with options to access the keypad, just in case I need to key in something, but that's about it), without any way to access Contacts or Favorites tabs of the phone's Dialer.

If press `Home` I get the home screen and I can select (run) any app there, but as soon as I select the `Contacts` app, all I get is the `Dialer` screen back! (call in progress...)

Is this the standard behavior of every dialer/contacts app on Android smartphones?

Is there any way or workaround to access my contact information while call is in progress? (e.g. while talking with someone who asks me for a phone number of someone else in my Contacts list).

Comment: One thing for sure - this is not a common behavior on phones especially Android. You should be able to access contacts while a call is in progress.

Comment: @MANI Thank you. My smartphone is an iRulu U2 running KitKat. I wonder why iRulu released a smartphone with such severe limitation. Is there an alternate dialer and/or contacts app that can replace the built-in ones? The dialer needs to support [dual-SIM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_SIM).

Comment: There are too many apps. I don't know if they support dual Sim. Try true dailer app and the similar ones.